# Update Owner of Account with Sales Rep associated with Account

Tags: apex, soql, error, update, execute-anonymous

**I am new to APEX Code and I am having some trouble accomplishing a task assigned to me**

I am trying to execute anonymous code that will get all accounts where the owner is a specific name. Then update the account owner with the sales rep associated. Here is the code I currently have:

```
List<Account> acc = new List<Account>();
acc = [Select Id, Sales_Rep_Name__c From Account Where Owner.name = 'Bishop Lafer'];
List<User> usr = new List<User>();
for(Account ac:acc){
   usr = [Select Id From User Where Name =: ac.Sales_Rep_Name__c];
   ac.OwnerName = usr.get(0).Id; 
}
```

I am getting this error:

System.LimitException: Too many SOQL queries: 101

I tried to do the following:

```
for(Account ac:acc){
    ac.OwnerName = ac.Sales_Rep_Name__c;     
}
```

However you can only update the Account Owner using the Owner.Id

How can I accomplish this seemingly simple task?

Any insight is greatly appreciated, thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `OwnerId` value. Note that you can't set a null value, so unless `Sales_Rep_Name__c` is required, you should add a null check. If you need to query the users by name, its' a four step process.

**Step 1: Query Accounts to Update**

```
List<Account> records = [
    SELECT Sales_Rep_Name__c FROM Account
    WHERE Owner.Name = 'Somebody'
    AND Sales_Rep_Name__c != null
];
```

**Step 2: Query/Map Users**

```
Set<String> names = new Set<String>();
for (Account record : records)
{
    names.add(record.Sales_Rep_Name__c);
}

Map<String, User> users = new Map<String, User>();
for (User user : [SELECT Name FROM User WHERE Name IN :names])
{
    users.put(user.Name, user);
}
```

**Step 3: Set OwnerId**

```
for (Account record : records)
{
    User rep = users.get(record.Sales_Rep_Name__c);
    if (rep != null)
    {
        record.OwnerId = rep.Id;
    }
}
```

**Step 4: Commit the Update**

```
update records;
```

Comment: I ran the code you suggested and I received this error:

System.StringException: Invalid id: (Sales Rep Name)

The Sales_Rep_Name__c is a full name not an Id, I need the Id of the user whose name = Sales_Rep_Name__c

Comment: See the updated snippet. @Pohsible

Comment: Thanks, I ran the updated snippet but no changes took effect. Do I need to update the Account object?

Comment: Yeah, I thought that part was obvious so I didn't include it in any of the snippets. Updated.

Comment: The code executed however there are still acounts Who Have Sales Reps associated with the same Owner that we used to select the accounts in the first query. @AdrianLarson